# Apache 2.4 proxy with single page static site

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have running Jira on my server with proxy like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.name.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    <LocationMatch /jira>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/jira
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/jira
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

And also I would like to have `index.html` in `/var/www/html/my_site` accessible through www.server.name.com while jira should be accessible through www.server.name.com/jira.

So far I have managed to do either infinite loops with mod_rewrite or other unsuccessful attempt to good redirect. Maybe mod_rewrite is not the best option?

My conf file for static site is quite standard:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName server.name.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-site/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my-site.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my-site.access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/my-site/>
        Options +Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks 
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You are not using mod_rewrite in your examples. And what do you want to rewrite in the first place? your first block only misses the DocumentRoot directive.

Comment: I was recommended to use mod_rewrite to rewrite / to /my-site so when you access the https://www.server.name.com you will be moved to the static site `RewriteRule ^/((?!jira))$ /my-site`

Comment: Well, you can't have the redirect and show your static page as the index page of the server. You have to choose one of those two options.

Comment: adding document root to proxy.conf solved the issue (thx). But I would like to have possibility to disable either jira or static site with `a2dissite`
EDIT: Now I see that its not possible to have both options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the document root in your first block.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.name.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-site/

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    <LocationMatch /jira>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/jira
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/jira
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

That's all.